# In Postgresql, after pg_dump the access privileges on the database itself are not restored

Tags: postgresql, backup, permissions, pg-dump

Suppose user foo owns a database gee, and user foo has granted user bar with all access privileges on database gee

```
gee=> \l
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 gee       | foo      | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/foo              +
           |          |          |             |             | foo=CTc/foo          +
           |          |          |             |             | bar=CTc/foo
```

We dump this database,

```
$ pg_dump -U foo -v -f gee.dump gee
```

In database gee user bar has created a schema. So because all of these users we restore database gee as user postgres (after user foo has created a database goo),

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -d goo -f gee.dump
```

User bar does not have the access privileges on the database goo. But inside database goo every privilege is OK, for all users, on schemas and tables.

```
goo=> \l
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 goo       | foo      | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

Why are the access privileges on the database itself not restored?

Comment: try use a superuser instead when pg_dump.

Comment: Does it emit a bunch of errors during pg_dump? Like, say, errors about GRANT and a user not existing?

Comment: @francs, it does not help.

Comment: @CraigRinger No, no errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why are the access privileges on the database itself not restored?

[It's a bug, or a design oversight](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1VYMqi-0001P4-P4@wrigleys.postgresql.org). Though the responder to that report doesn't think so.

`pg_dumpall --globals-only` doesn't dump rights on the database. Neither does `pg_dump` as part of the database dump.

So grants on databases only get included in a full `pg_dumpall`.

I'll make some noise about it by poking [this thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5280E2AE.8070106@usit.uio.no).